# None intent when I scan an NFC tag

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

I'm trying to create a simple NFC Reader application but when I try to scan a card my application seems to be dead.

I've tried to edit the android manifest and add a nfc_tech_filter.xml, but I see always the same result.

I've written these:

MainAvtivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        print("ehi")
        Toast.makeText(this, intent.action, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

nfc_tech_filter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    <!-- class name -->
</tech-list>
```

I think that should appear a Toast with the name of the intent but nothing appears.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you add the error log?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I don't have any error... It seems like my card doesn't touch the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure but try this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ehi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
    }

    override fun onResume(){
        // TODO: nfcAdapter enableForeground
    }

    override fun onPause(){
        // TODO: nfcAdapter disableForeground()
    }
}
```

It must work.